# add attachments to a feature layer

Tags: android, kotlin, maps, arcgis, esri

how to get ArcGis feature from servicefeature table to perform add attachments.

I tried this example and built on it with a different feature layer.
https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-maps-sdk-kotlin-samples/tree/main/edit-feature-attachments

I logged few messages such as the image size, name and if the adding operation is finished but when I check the uploaded attachments there is non. I check the docs as well but didn't find any example or a written code that helped. it lacks in that department

this is what I attempted, check the screen shot the 3rd one after trying to upload a image.

````
private fun addFeatureAttachment(selectedImageUri: Uri) {
        // display a loading dialog
        val dialog = createLoadingDialog("Adding feature attachment").also {
            it.show()
        }

        // create an input stream at the selected URI
        contentResolver.openInputStream(selectedImageUri)?.use { imageInputStream ->
            // get the byte array of the image input stream
            val imageBytes: ByteArray = imageInputStream.readBytes()
            // create the attachment name with the current time
            val attachmentName = "attachment_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png"
            Log.d("attachment","attachment_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png")

            lifecycleScope.launch {
                selectedArcGISFeature?.let { arcGISFeature ->
                    // add the attachment to the selected feature
                    arcGISFeature.addAttachment(
                        name = attachmentName,
                        contentType = "image/png",
                        data = imageBytes
                    ).onFailure {
                        return@launch showError(it.message.toString())
                    }
                    // update the feature changes in the loaded service feature table
                    serviceFeatureTable.updateFeature(arcGISFeature).getOrElse {
                        return@launch showError(it.message.toString())
                    }
                }
                applyServerEdits(dialog)
            }
        }
    }
 private suspend fun applyServerEdits(dialog: AlertDialog) {
        // close the bottom sheet, as it will be created
        // after service changes are made
        bottomSheet?.dismiss()

        // apply edits to the server
        val updatedServerResult = serviceFeatureTable.applyEdits()
        updatedServerResult.onSuccess { edits ->
            dialog.dismiss()

            // check that the feature table was successfully updated
            if (edits.isEmpty()) {
                showToast("not")

                return showError(getString(R.string.failure_edit_results))

            }
            // if the edits were made successfully, create the bottom sheet to display new changes.
            selectedArcGISFeature?.let { createBottomSheet(it) }
        }.onFailure {
            showError(it.message.toString())
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }

    fun selectAttachment() {
        val mediaIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        activityResultLauncher.launch(mediaIntent)
    }
    ```
````